# Find $T^*(x,y)$ with the given inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inner-products, adjoint-operators

Let $T:\mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}^2$ be a inner product space, $T(x,y)=(2ix+y, -x-iy)$ and the inner product $<(x_1, x_2), (y_1, y_2)>=4x_1\overline{y_1}+9x_2\overline{y_2}$.

Find $T^*(x,y)$

I found out that the canonical basis $C=\left \{(1,0), (0,1) \right \}$ isn't orthonormal (but orthogonal) for the given inner product, so I orthonormalized  it and got $C'= \left \{(1/2,0), (0,1/3) \right \}$.

Then I used the definition for adjoint transformations:

- $<T^*(1/2, 0), (x,y)>=<(1/2,0), T(x,y)>$

  $<(1/2, 0), (2ix+y, -x-iy)>=-4ix+2y$
- $<T^*(0, 1/3), (x,y)>=<(0, 1/3), T(x,y)>$

  $<(0, 1/3), (2ix+y, -x-iy)>=-3x-3iy$

So $T^*(x,y)=(-4ix+2y, -3x-3iy)$, but the correct answer is $T^*(x,y)=(-2ix-9/4y, 4/9x+iy)$.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would use $T^*(x,y) = \langle T^*(x,y), (1/2,0) \rangle (1/2,0) + \langle T^*(x,y), (0,1/3) \rangle (0, 1/3)$.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get the correct answer. Could you please explain a little more?

Comment: In your original question, how are you getting from the calculations of $\langle T^*(1/2, 0), (x,y) \rangle$ and $\langle T^*(0, 1/3), (x,y) \rangle$ (which should be $-4i \bar x + 2 \bar y$ and $-3 \bar x - 3i \bar y$ by the way) to a value for $T^*(x,y)$?  I don't see the connection at all.  At most, you could read off what $T^*(1/2,0)$ and $T^*(0,1/3)$ would be, and then say $T^*(x,y) = 2x T^*(1/2,0) + 3y T^*(0,1/3)$.

Comment: Ok, I get what you're saying, but now I have $T^*(x,y)=2x(-4i, -3)+3y(1, -3i)=(-8ix+3y, -6x-9iy)$? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If $\langle T^*(1/2, 0), (x,y) \rangle = -4i \bar x + 2 \bar y = 4 (-i) \bar x + 9 (\frac{2}{9}) \bar y = \langle (-i, \frac{2}{9}), (x,y) \rangle$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{C}$ then that would mean you must have $T^*(1/2, 0) = (-i, \frac{2}{9})$...